# "it fulfills its full business name"

Tags: possessives

> *The Client hereby undertakes to comply with the Collection Hub’s Terms and Conditions and for the evidence of this acceptance **it fulfills its full business name**, name of the acting representative and presses the button “ACCEPT”.*

I do not understand why the passage in bold has this form. Why is "it" before "its". I think it is the "client" who is supposed to fulfill its full business name. So there is no need to use any pronoun. But in this case I would choose the possessive "their".

Comment: That **fulfills** is a malapropism, possibly by a non-native speaker.  **for** should be **as**.  It should be **evidence** not **the evidence**.  This is not idiomatic English.

Comment: Do you mean "fulfil" vs. "fulfill"? But "fulfill" fits in the context or not?

Comment: No, "fill in" is the verb they want.

Comment: Yeah it's a weird, almost dissociated phrasing like the infamous *"It rubs the lotion on its skin or else it gets the hose."*  The Client is still a person, not an object.

Comment: In legal agreements, it's common to refer to Client as "it". That's not the strange thing about this sentence. A standard way of stating that the following actions constitute acceptance of terms would go like this: *By filling in the full business name, the name of the acting representative, and pressing the ACCEPT button, Client is agreeing to comply with the terms and conditions....*